# Change border of last row clicked in a dynamic table (using <ul>)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rshutxpj/3/

As you can see, when you click on the rows, there is a little border appearing. I basically want to only have the border change on the last row clicked, but I don't know what event to use to bring the previous row I clicked with no border. What would be the best way to do that?

P.S. I cant use the any type of "losefocus" or similar, because I got many table on my page and the last row clicked on this particular table need to stay visible to the user. Think it the same way as many groups of radiobox.

Here is the code:

```
<ul class="UploadTable" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="false" style="min-width:350px">
    <li style="text-align: center !important">
        <label>UPLOAD SCHEDULE</label>
    </li>
    <li data-role="list-divider">
        <div class="ui-grid-b">
            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:33%">Header 1</div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:34%">Header 2</div>
            <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:33%">Header 3</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="addedTargetRow" class="fitting">
        <a href="#" onclick="this.style.border='2px solid #000099;'">
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div id="THW_ID" class="ui-block-a" style="width:33%">info1</div>
                <div id="POS" class="ui-block-b" style="width:34%">info2</div>
                <div id="IP" class="ui-block-c" style="width:33%">Info3</div>
            </div>                                                                                                                   </a>                                                                                                                     </li>
    <li id="addedTargetRow" class="fitting">
        <a href="#" onclick="this.style.border='2px solid #000099;'">
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div id="THW_ID" class="ui-block-a" style="width:33%">info1</div>
                <div id="POS" class="ui-block-b" style="width:34%">info2</div>
                <div id="IP" class="ui-block-c" style="width:33%">Info3</div>
            </div>                                                                                                                   </a>                                                                                                                     </li>
    <li id="addedTargetRow" class="fitting">
        <a href="#" onclick="this.style.border='2px solid #000099;'">
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div id="THW_ID" class="ui-block-a" style="width:33%">info1</div>
                <div id="POS" class="ui-block-b" style="width:34%">info2</div>
                <div id="IP" class="ui-block-c" style="width:33%">Info3</div>
            </div>                                                                         </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you have proders to all rows and outline only to the clicked one. So what is your question? I don't understand you

Comment: Please post your JavaScript code in the question as well.

Comment: Isn't your fiddle already working the way you like?

Comment: @Ishettyl "I basically want to only have the border change on the last row clicked". Right now, when I click on the second row, the previous one still have the border changed.

Comment: @PeterKA There is no other other javascript in this (as you can see in the fiddle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. You have duplicate IDs.
> 2. Why do want to have `onclick` on each anchor.(removed in demo)

Use this JS

```
$(document).on('click', '.fitting', function () {
    $('.fitting').removeAttr('style');    // removes all previous borders
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid #000099')// add border to current element
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edvefasr/)

**Warning**:As you have only border in style attribute , removing it will not effect anything, Suppose if you have other styles along with border don't use `.removeAttr('style');` , Use `.css('border', 'none')` like below

```
$(document).on('click', '.fitting', function () {
    $('.fitting').css('border', 'none')// removes all previous borders
    $(this).css('border', '2px solid #000099')// add border to current element
})
```

Update :

If there are multiple tables then use this `$(this).parents('table').find('.fitting').css('border', 'none')`
this finds the `fitting` elements of the table in which the row is clicked, excluding the same elements in other tables in DOM

Comment: Wow, that works exactly what how I wanted. Actually, I found a solution working, but it was with duplicated ID, so I think I will take yours... But I wanna know, does duplicate ID is just a really bad habit (like using goto) or just something that might generate errors?

Comment: duplicate Ids is bad practice , use class if you want to use same selector for all or just append a number. it will not generate errors but while working with jquery , you may not get proper results

Comment: @J Santosh Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: @J Santosh's answer will toggle all links in all of the tables and the question mentioned that there are multipe tables on the page would all lose their highlighting.

Having your onclick links on the list items will make this messy and is not performant (as I'll go thru below). To stay within The solution you are looking for is:

```
onclick="var links=this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.fitting a') || [], i = links.length;  for (;!!i;i--) { links[i].style.border='none'; } this.style.border='2px solid #000099';"
```

This will make sure you are only removing the highlighted row from that table.

**HOWEVER**, There are some very concerning things about this structure.

1. Your id's are not unique.  You should remove the id attributes.
2. You can use the href=javascript:"/* onclick stuff goes here */" instead of adding an onclick attribute.
3. There is no need to use anchor tags in the li as you are doing. Adding extra DOM items makes your DOM heavier and the page slower.  I suspect you are only adding those because you want the pointer icon. You can fix that with CSS.
4. Your onclicks will all need to be updated the same way and makes your code less reusable. Adding eventHandlers to every li also is expensive in that the function isn't cached and requires extra resources for each DOM element.
5. Setting the style purely in javascript might be better done in CSS since it will be tied to your page layout styling. Create a class called "selected" or something similar and add the class onclick.

SO here is how I would code it:

HTML:

**REMOVE ALL OF YOUR LINKS!** You are using anchor tags wrong! Also, remove all of your id's.

CSS:

```
li.fitting { cursor: pointer; }

li.fitting.selected { border: 2px solid #000099 }
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('li.fitting').on('click', function() {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML state of `:focus` and the JS "blur" event, hooked using the HTML attribute `onblur`. So, you would amend your `onclick` to `this.style.border='2px solid #000099';this.focus();` and add `onblur="this.style.border='none';"` to that same link.

Comment: @Olivier B Like I said : " I cant use the any type of "losefocus" or similar, because I got many table on my page and the last row clicked on this particular table need to stay visible to the user. Think it the same way as many groups of radiobox." The moment you click somewhere else in the on page the, the border disappear.